# Why $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus K$ connected $\implies {\mathbb{C}}\setminus K$ connected? ($K $ compact)

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $\hat{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ denote the extended complex plane, with the usual topology.That is $U$ such that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ and the neighbourhoods of $\{\infty\}$  $U_{\infty}=\mathbb{C} \setminus K \cup \{\infty\}$ with $K$ a compact subset of the complex plane.

We need to show that if $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ then $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus K$ connected $\implies {\mathbb{C}}\setminus K$ connected

I tried to prove it assuming a clopen non-trivial subset of  $ {\mathbb{C}}\setminus K$ . Showing that this set is open is easy but how can i show that is also closed in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus K$?

Comment: Can you reedit the question in a more clear form?

Comment: For instance, please define the terms you use(C, C-hat, K)

Comment: Sorry, I hope it's clear now. I should write my questions carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $K$ is compact, it is closed and bounded. There is thus a ball $B$ of some radius $r<\infty$ covering $K$. Since $\Bbb C\setminus B$ is connected, $\Bbb C\setminus K$ has exactly one unbounded component.
Let $U$ be a clopen subset of $\Bbb C\setminus K$ containing the unbounded component. Then $U$ is open in $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C\setminus U$ is compact, hence $U\cup\{\infty\}$ is open in $\hat{\Bbb C}$. But it's also closed in $\hat{\Bbb C}\setminus K$ since $(\hat{\Bbb C}\setminus K)\setminus(U\cup\{\infty\}) = {\Bbb C}\setminus (K\cup U)$ is open.

Comment: it is always the case that   $U$ contains  the unbounded component?

Comment: @Abellan: If some point in the unbounded component of $\Bbb C\setminus K$ is contained in a clopen subset $U$ of $\Bbb C\setminus K$ (there's always at least one such clopen subset), then $U$ must contain the entire unbounded component because it is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose WLOG that $0 \in K$, and apply the homeomorphism $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ of $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$. Then $\hat{\Bbb{C}} \setminus K$ is mapped into some bounded open set $D \subset \Bbb{C}$ containing $0$. $D$ is path connected because it is connected. Can you show that $D \setminus \{0 \}$ is path connected as well (paths do not need to pass through $0$, because $D$ is open, so "there is enough space" to go around $0$ and avoid it)? Then conclude.

Comment: I did like this argument a lot. However, it is necessary to choose the homeomorphism such that  $D$ is bounded? Thanks!

Comment: I used the simplest homemorphism I had in mind to get rid of the infinity point. What comes out is a bounded open set, because it is an open set of $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$ far from $\infty$. Actually boundedness of $D$ is not so relevant: what is relevant is path connectedness.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking that you can get also path connectedness with an unbounded $D$.